# Terminal Server does not map Local Drives

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, windows-server-2000

We have a Windows 2000 Server, running Terminal Services in Application Server Mode.
When I start and RDP session to it, I can select to map my local drives to the server, but they are not available from within the RDP session.   When I connect to other servers, the drives are available.  Now the other servers are Windows 2003/2008 and are running in Administrative Mode, not Application Server Mode, so I'm not sure if either of these are the cause.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a limitation of Windows 2000 Server.  It's been a while, but I seem to recall there is a resource kit utility called FileCopy (rdpclip).  This doesn't map the drive, but it does allow copy/paste files/folder between local and remote drives.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229